# How to declare local variables in macro asm of gas like decalaring it in macro asm with %local in macro asm of nasm or local in macro asm of masm?

Tags: assembly, nasm, masm, gnu-assembler, att

the way to declare local variables in macro asm of nasm is like:%local old_ax:word,and the way to declare local variables in macro asm of masm is like:local old_ax:WORD,so what's the way to declare local variables in macro asm of gas?

Comment: Read the [manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Altmacro.html). `.altmacro` and `LOCAL`.

Comment: Thanks a lot anyway! But your answer to my question isn't what I want. Maybe I haven't state the question clearly. The "local variables"  stated above is allocated in the stack;the meaning of "local variables"  is just like it in C language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gas` is primarily intended as a compiler backend, not for human use. As such, it's lacking some features, among others this one. You can of course try to make a macro to do this, something along these lines:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
.globl main

.macro local head, tail:vararg
# assume dwords for simplicity
.set localsize, localsize + 4
.set \head, -localsize
.ifnb \tail
local \tail
.endif
.endm

main:
    .set localsize, 0
    local old_ax, old_dx
    enter localsize, 0
    mov [ebp+old_ax], ax
    mov [ebp+old_dx], dx
    leave
    ret
```

But in general you can just use the equates for stack offsets directly, such as:

```
main:
    .set old_ax, 4
    .set old_dx, 0
    sub esp, 8
    mov [esp+old_ax], ax
    mov [esp+old_dx], dx
    add esp, 8
    ret
```

Comment: So,I would allocate local variables manually,unwilling,because the gas hasn't helped me do that! Thanks a lot!