# Is GNU GAS Macro support infinity macro argument?

Tags: assembly, macros, gnu-assembler

I expect I can access infinity macro argument in specified position in x64 machine.

For example

```
.macro myMacro infinityParam
  mov rax, \infinityParam[0]
  mov rbx, \infinityParam[1]
  mov rcx, \infinityParam[2]
.endm
```

So I can use that macro like this:

```
myMacro 5,9,8,6
```

`rax` will be 5.
`rbx` will be 9.
`rcx` will be 8.

So how do I make infinity argument in macro?

I'm sure it's possible because
`.int`,`.word`, and another data declaration is supported to do it.
Eg:

```
.word 2,7,4,9, ...
```

UPDATE:
I have clue but it's not what I want.

```
.macro myMacroB param1, param2
  mov rax, \param1
  mov rbx, \param2
.endm

.macro myMacroA infParam
  myMacroB \infParam
.endm

_start:
  myMacroA "6,9"
```

As you see I can make infinity parameter with using string parameter,`rax will be 6` and `rbx will be 9`.

But it's not what I want because `myMacroB` still finite param, I'm just giving clue.

Comment: IIRC, you might need a recursive macro to get 1 arg at a time with a **variadic** macro.

Comment: [How to declare local variables in macro asm of gas like decalaring it in macro asm with %local in macro asm of nasm or local in macro asm of masm?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34749659) shows an example of using `.macro foo arg1, tail:vararg` with recursion to pick apart a list of args.  After checking the manual (https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Macro.html), I searched for `site:stackoverflow.com assembly gas ".macro" vararg` to find that example.  You can grab args as many at a time as you want, e.g. in pairs with 2 args before the vararg.